# Divide et impera for matrices rotating

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, divide-and-conquer, blit, rotational-matrices

I have tried to solve the 2nd problem  b and d subproblems from this exercise: http://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs473/sp2010/homework/hw1.pdf

I solved the b to the following way:[image: 2/b problem solution]

My first question is that: Is my solution correct for the problem 2/b?
My second question is: What I supposed to do the in problem 2/d? This a bit strange for me.

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: by the looks of it, this question is more appropriate to be posted on math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From reading the second paragraph of the problem, it seems to me that your answer is not correct for part 2b.  My reading was that a 2^n rotate would take 5 blits of 2^(n-1).  If this is correct, then your equation should be

B(2^n) = 5 * B(2^(n-1)) = 25 * B(2^(n-2)) = ... = 5^n * B(1)

Where B(x) is the number of blits for x.  (Sorry for not knowing how to do fancy equations.)

For 2d, I read it as saying what is the time complexity of B(2^n).  Give it a try and let's see what comes out of it.

Let me know what you think.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately I think that you are a completely wrong way.

Comment: You've left me hanging.  Do you think that 2b is not about counting blits?  It explicitly asks for the number of blits, not the blits and recursion steps together.  I took that to mean only look at the blue arrows for this subset of the problem.  Your calculation seems to look at everything together.  As with all things in life, I could be totally wrong, but the problem interests me.  I would be curious as to the final answer when you find out.  Thanks.